# Eulerian and Hamiltonian graph theory problem

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

I am new to this subject. I am trying do a graph theory example
[image]

[image]

(iii) There is no Euler cycle since some degree of vertices are odd
(iv)  Since there are more than two vertices which has odd degrees this is not a semi eulerien so thus not a noncyclic euler graph

(v) $ A\to B \to C \to E \to D \to A$

(vi) $A\to B \to C \to E \to D$

Can anyone verify my answer?

Answer (score 1):

These solutions seem correct, but it's not clear what the definition of a "noncyclic Hamiltonian path" would be. It could just mean a Hamilton path which is not a cycle, or it could mean a Hamilton path which cannot be closed by the inclusion of a single edge. If the first definition is the one given in your text, then the path you give is correct. If the second definition is the one given, then (B,C,D,A,E) suffices as there is no edge between B and E.